# Cloning isomorphic-git repo from another mobile device?

Tags: git, isomorphic-git

I've got a mobile application (Apache Cordova, both on iOS and Android) that I'd like to fold a git repo into for content sharing / version control. My thought is to eventually add some sort of QR code display, so that users can join a known an existing repo and make necessary edits -- but that it would be just a group of mobile devices.

Is it possible to set up a git DVCS using *just* mobile devices? Or do I need to have at least one node be on a server somewhere (`GitHub` etc.) so there's a URL to point the `clone` command to? ...and if it is possible, what does the URL look like on the mobile device that does the `init` for the repo?

Comment: Git is decentralized, you don't need a central server necessarily.

Comment: Yup. But how exactly do you clone from a repo on a mobile device? Or do you need to clone a desktop somewhere with a stable URL/IP? It's the details I'm getting stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the devs were on Gitter, so I posted over there. Here's the answer from **jcubic** on `isomorphic-git`'s dev team:

> If you want to use git commands that interact with the remote you need to have a server. But server is not needed to use git. But without a server you will need to figure out a way to send repositories from one phone to the other phone.  Another problem is that you will need to sync two directories with two git repos you will need to figure out how to do this.
> With server you have this out of the box